# Pattern matching in dictionary using python

Tags: python

In the following dictionary,can the elements be sorted according the last prefix in the key

```
opt_dict=(
{'option1':1,
 'nonoption2':1,
 'nonoption3':12,
 'option4':6,
 'nonoption5':5,
 'option6':1,
 'option7':1,
  })

    for key,val in opt_dict.items():
           if "answer" in key:  //match keys last prefix and print output

               print "found option 1,4,6,7" //in ascending order
           elif "nonanswer" in key: //match keys last prefix and print output
               print "found option 2,3,5 "  //in ascending order
```

Thanks..

Comment: Variable names like `a1`, `a2`, etc. are a "design smell", indicating that you probably should be thinking in terms of a list named `a`, instead of creating a bunch of variables with numbers on the end. Like variable names, if a dict key itself contains some aspect of its data, then how will you know what key to ask for? For the item in position 3, should you use key "option3" or "nonoption3"? Why not use a list like `opts=[(,),(True,1),(False,1),(False,12),(True,6),]`, then you can access `opts[3][0]` to see if that opt is an option or nonoption. A list of namedtuple would be even better.

Comment: K thanks this is can solve the issue here..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for k,v in sorted(opt_dict.items(),
                  key = lambda item: int(item[0][len("option"):])
                            if item[0].startswith("option")
                            else int(item[0][len("nonoption"):])
                    ):
    print k,v
```

Prints:

```
option1 1
nonoption2 1
nonoption3 12
option4 6
nonoption5 5
option6 1
option7 1
```

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error in the line if item[0].startswith("option")

Comment: What version of Python are you running?  Works on 2.5.4.

Comment: Maybe you're using a Python version <2.5 where the `x = a if b else c` syntax was introduced?